# Queries to get unpaid and unpaid invoices

Tags: php, array, laravel

Here is my code:

```
add_hook('ClientAreaPageInvoices', 1, function($vars) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION["uid"];
    $today = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    $query_1 = Capsule::table('tblinvoices')
        ->select(Capsule::raw('SUM(total) as total_aberto'))
        ->where(array('userid' => $user_id, 'status' => 'Unpaid'))
        ->get();
    $query_2 = Capsule::table('tblinvoices')
        ->select(Capsule::raw('SUM(total) as total_vencido'))
        ->where(array('userid' => $user_id, 'status' => 'Unpaid'))
        ->whereDate('duedate', '<=', $today)
        ->get();
    $query_3 = Capsule::table('tblinvoices')
        ->select(Capsule::raw('SUM(total) as total_pago'))
        ->where(array('userid' => $user_id, 'status' => 'Paid'))
        ->get();
    $array_1 = json_decode(json_encode($query_1), True); 
    $array_2 = json_decode(json_encode($query_2), True); 
    $array_3 = json_decode(json_encode($query_3), True); 
    $totalAberto = $array_1[0]['total_aberto'];
    $totalVencido = $array_2[0]['total_vencido'];
    $totalPago = $array_3[0]['total_pago'];
    return array ('totalAberto' => $totalAberto,
                  'totalVencido' => $totalVencido,
                  'totalPago' => $totalPago);
});
```

Is there any way to simplify the entire code in general?

It works well - I just want to learn other practices to make this type of consultation in a more optimized, and simplified way.

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be a section in your code that you repeat three times. This can probably be placed in a separate function. Something like this:

```
function getInvoiceTotal($status, $onlyOverdue = FALSE)
{
    $query = Capsule::table('tblinvoices');
    $query->select(Capsule::raw('SUM(total) as total'))
          ->where(['userid' => $_SESSION['uid'], 
                   'status' => $status]);
    if ($onlyOverdue && ($status == 'Unpaid')) {
        $query->whereDate('duedate', '<=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
    }    
    return $query->get()->total;        
}


add_hook('ClientAreaPageInvoices', 1, function($vars) {
    return ['totalAberto'  => getInvoiceTotal('Unpaid'), 
            'totalVencido' => getInvoiceTotal('Unpaid', TRUE), 
            'totalPago'    => getInvoiceTotal('Paid')];
});
```

Regretably I don't have Laravel installed so I cannot test this code, but I think the general idea is clear. Perhaps someone with more knowledge of Laravel can add to this answer?

Some notes:

- I changed `array(....)` to `[....]`.
- I didn't understand the `json_decode(json_encode())` bit. Perhaps to go from objects to arrays? I don't see what's wrong with using the actual objects. Here's where I have most doubt that my code is correct, since I haven't tested it.
- I left out a lot of variables you used. Using variables, with good names, can make code easier to read, but in really good code, when a variable is only used once, it shouldn't be necessary.
- I strongly advise you to write your code in English only. I had to find out what the meaning of 'Aberto', 'Vencido' and 'Pago' is. Not every programmer speaks Protuguese.

Comment: When I see `json_decode(json_encode())` used (deliberately, correctly), it is to ensure that the whole multi-dimensional iterable structure is all array-type or all object-type.  ...but I don't know that this is useful here.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, that's what I assumed, but why is that conversion needed? This has probably to do with my lack of Laravel knowledge.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Very cool your code, really with a separate function everything is simplified, however it did not work for me, it returned all zero (0,00) values.

Comment: It needs some basic debugging. The idea is sound, but clearly there's still some kind of error in it.

Answer (score 0):

### SUM aggregates

Instead of selecting the `SUM` aggregate manually:

> ```
> ->select(Capsule::raw('SUM(total) as total_aberto'))
> ```

The [`Builder::sum()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_sum) aggregate method can be used:

```
->sum('total')
```

Is there a model defined like `Invoice`?

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class Invoice extends Model 
{

    protected $table = 'tblinvoices';

}
```

Presuming such a model existed, the code like this:

> ```
> $query_1 = Capsule::table('tblinvoices')
>     ->select(Capsule::raw('SUM(total) as total_aberto'))
>     ->where(array('userid' => $user_id, 'status' => 'Unpaid'))
>     ->get();
> ```

could be simplified to this, using the [methods to retrieve Single Models / Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models):

```
$totalAberto = App\Models\Invoice::where(['userid' => $user_id, 'status' => 'Unpaid'])
                                  ->sum('total');
```

#### Array syntax

There isn't anything wrong with using `array()` but as of the time of writing, [PHP has Active support for versions 8.0 and 7.4](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php), and since PHP 5.4 arrays can be declared with [short array syntax (PHP 5.4)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), as was used in my sample at the end of the section above.